# CGI cannot compile python file

Tags: python, apache, cgi

OSX 10.12 and apache 2.4 （system-provided）

I have configured the apache httpd.conf file, AddHandler as `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py`

Directory also add ExecCGI

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/">
  #Options Indexes MultiViews
  Options ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  # OSX 10.10 / Apache 2.4
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache`sudo apachectl restart`

But it cannot compile the files, it will print directly, but HTML is ok.
This issue has blocked me one week, does someone help me? Thanks!

Note:
python file work well in Pycharm.
Python environment aslo correct

**Screenshot**:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You configured the cgi-script handling only for the "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/" directory.

Comment: what do you  meaning?
I configured cgi-script in <Directory> and AddHandler, both not work